# Aws composite alarm not working because of syntax error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am getting this syntax error for below mentioned CF

```
    CMP:
Type: AWS::CloudWatch::CompositeAlarm
DependsOn:
 - QueueUploadWorkerpproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible
 - QueueDataWorkerApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage
Properties:
  AlarmName: CMP
  AlarmDescription: CompositeAlarm
  AlarmRule: (ALARM([!Ref 'ALARM1']) AND ALARM([!Ref 'ALARM2']))
  AlarmActions:
       - !Ref SNSTOPIC
```

Resource handler returned message: "Error in AlarmRule [Unsupported token ''Alarms1']' at char 13, must be: ')'] (Service: AmazonCloudWatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 726ebbbd-2e30-447e-9944-4d72d9b63f2c; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: 92f75190-0b7e-e6f5-f5c0-d18377a82c4c, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) to reference your `ALARM1` and `ALARM2`:

```
AlarmRule: !Sub "(ALARM(['${ALARM1}']) AND ALARM(['${ALARM2}']))"
```

You have to double check the syntax for the rule, but now `ALARM1` and `ALARM2` will be correctly referenced.

Comment: @wasimmir Because its incorrect syntax. You have to use Sub if you want to reference values in strings.

Comment: it didn't work. it is referring to arn in a different and gave me below error

Resource handler returned message: "Could not save the composite alarm as alarms [arn:aws:cloudwatch:eu-west-1:123456789:alarm:['Alarm1'], arn:aws:cloudwatch:eu-west-1:123456789:alarm:['Alarm2']] in the alarm rule do not exist (Service: AmazonCloudWatch; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 55b75e37-ed60-4fed-a2fc-3576acf5dddb; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: e8e41628-4296-8107-74fe-0af24cc066b6, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)

Comment: @wasimmir Please share your full code, not the few lines. Its difficult to know what is the context of your error without the complete example.

Comment: The code in in actual question , It works when I hard core queue name like how it is mentioned in the aws document, but when I try to !Ref it then I get error.
like how it is here in this URL
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudwatch-compositealarm.html

Comment: @wasimmir You can't use !Ref. Its wrong syntax. What is ALARM1 and ALARM2? Your question does not provide their definition.

Comment: Alarm1 and Alarm2 are just two resources, or what I say is two CW alarms which I am later using in the composite alarm

Answer (score 1):

I'm encountering the same issue and by the looks on my side it is because the alarm arn has spaces in it.